# How can I get my text to be centered on the same line as my image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to line this logo and the text on the same line, but have the logo on the left hand corner of the site, and the text be centered. Here's what it looks like now and what the CSS and HTML is so far.

[image: What the site looks like now]

Here's my current code:

```css
#title {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #E03DA7;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline;
  align-content: right;
}
body {
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#navbar {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center
}
#mainpara {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 750px;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: sans-serif
}
img {
  max-width: 100px
}
```

```html
<img src="WOW_logo_RGB.jpg">
<h1 id="title">Welcome, to WOW Virtual.</h1>
<h3 id="navbar">About Us | Live Radar | Why Join?</h3>

<p id="mainpara">Welcome to WOW Virtual, a fresh new Virtual Airline for the Flight Simulator community. We offer only the best for our pilots, and strive to maintain the best service for any of our pilots. Interested? Join Today!</p>
```

Comment: Not sure why using table-cell go down voted. You  can check my code snippet and share your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired results with [Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/)

If you contain your `img` and `h1` in a container (say `header`), add the following CSS to the `header` tag

```
header { 
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center; /* align vertical */ 
 }
```

Results can be found here, with your modified code: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cwx9Lyv6/)

Comment: @Grant-Meder : If you decide to use flex box, kindly check **if it is well supported** in the target browsers for you application.  http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: @DavidChelliah, you're correct, that was not part of the requirements from OP's question. However, OP can reference [http://caniuse.com/](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). The sample above works well in IE11, the only modern browser which has partial support for Flex

Answer (score 0):

Have the text and picture in one div with text-align centered. Then you can center the div itself if you want it to be in the center.

Answer (score 0):

More of an hackish way, you can put the `img` and `h1` into a div with class `.header`.

Then set the `line-height` of the `div` to the height of the image:

```
.header {
  line-height:100px;
}
```

You can see the output [here](http://jsbin.com/hahurugeca/1/edit?html,css,output).

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this:

```css
#title, img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#title {
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/60/60/tech">
<h1 id="title">Welcome, to WOW Virtual.</h1>
<h3 id="navbar">About Us | Live Radar | Why Join?</h3>
```

**Edit:** If you want the text to be centered, you have to take another approach:

```css
#header {
    position: relative;
}
h1 {
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
#header img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 60px;
}
#navbar {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/60/60/tech">
    <h1>Welcome, to WOW Virtual.</h1>
</div>
<h3 id="navbar">About Us | Live Radar | Why Join?</h3>
```

By using `position:absolute` on the `img` tag, you ensure that the `h1` tag is centered to the full width of the page.

Comment: Your method is quite simple & I like it. But if there is an inline element in the next line, won't it be pulled to first line, after the Welcome text

Answer (score -1):

Normally with table tag, you can apply **Vertical align** property as **middle** for you table cells .

If you want to use the same property / behaviour for your div. Then use `display:table-row` to your parent (.header) and then display:table-cell to the child div around Logo and the text.

That would allow you to use `vertical-align:middle`.
check through the edit made by copying your initial code snippet. Let me know if you have any query

```css
.header{
  display:table-row;
}
.header > div{
display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
#title {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #E03DA7;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline;
  align-content: right;
}
body {
  align-content: center;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#navbar {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 25px;
  text-align: center
}
#mainpara {
  text-align: left;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 750px;
  font-size: 20px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: sans-serif
}
img {
  max-width: 100px
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <div>
      <img width="250" height="250" src="WOW_logo_RGB.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
      <h1 id="title">Welcome, to WOW Virtual.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h3 id="navbar">About Us | Live Radar | Why Join?</h3>

  <p id="mainpara">Welcome to WOW Virtual, a fresh new Virtual Airline for the Flight Simulator community. We offer only the best for our pilots, and strive to maintain the best service for any of our pilots. Interested? Join Today!</p>
</body>

</html>
```